# How can i use the reply_to_message_id in Telegram bot?

Tags: php, function, telegram, telegram-bot

I am making a personal small PHP Telegram Bot. But there is a problem I want to make a function which helps me to reply to user just by replying to the message he sent. Like when a user sends a message in the Bot it will forward the message to me.I want to reply to this user by replying to the message he sent.
I tried with the help of **[Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api)** but didnt succeed.

Here is the **[forwardMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#forwardmessage)** function which works

```
//forward msg
function forwardMessage($adminid,$chatId, $message_id){
$url = $GLOBALS["website"]."/forwardMessage 
chat_id=".$adminid."&from_chat_id=".$chatId."&message_id=".$message_id."&parse_mode=HTML";
file_get_contents($url);      
}
```

I tried to make a **[sendReply](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage)** function with the help of **API** but it does not work

```
//send reply
function sendReply($userId,$message, $reply_to_message_id){
$url = $GLOBALS["website"]."/sendMessage? 
chat_id=".$userId."&text=".$message."&reply_to_message_id=".$reply_to_message_id."&parse_mode=HTML";
file_get_contents($url);      
}
```

Comment: What was the error you received? Please provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @JairusMartin there was no error just the message was not sent to the sender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your Question, I guess you want to make a System like Livegram Bot. Here is the Code. DM Me on Telegram @NinjaNaveen if you Need Further Help :)

```
 $admin = "xxxx" //Admin ID
    $from_id = $update->message->from->id; //User ID
    $text = $update->message->text; //Message sent by Admin
    $replytomessage = $update->message->reply_to_message //A Reply to a Message 
    $replytomessageUSERID = $update->message->reply_to_message->from->id; //User ID of the replied to message user
    $replytomessageID = $update->message->reply_to_message->message_id; //Replied to Message ID
    
    
    //////////////
    
    if (isset($replytomessage) && $from_id == $admin){ //If A Reply exists and the ID is Admin ID
    
    sendMessage($replytomessageUSERID, $text, $message_id);
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your code has some errors in declaring values, but you can try this function:

```
function reply_to_message_id($chatId, $message, $message_id){
$url = $GLOBALS[website]."/sendMessage?chat_id=".$chatId."&text=".$message."&reply_to_message_id=".$message_id."&parse_mode=HTML&disable_web_page_preview=1";
file_get_contents($url);      
}
```